# MatLab algorithm for composite Simpson's rule

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I have tried, just for the fun of it, to write a MatLab-code for the composite Simpson's rule.  As far as I can see, the code is correct, but my answers are not as accurate as I would like.  If I try my code on the function f = cos(x) + e^(x^2), with a = 0, b = 1 and n = 7, my answer is roughly 1,9, when it should be 2,3.  If I use the algorithm available at Wikipedia, I get a very close approximation with n = 7, so my code is obviously not good enough.  If someone can see any mistakes in my code, I would really appreciate it!

```
function x = compsimp(a,b,n,f)
% The function implements the composite Simpson's rule

h = (b-a)/n;
x = zeros(1,n+1);
x(1) = a;
x(n+1) = b;
p = 0;
q = 0;

% Define the x-vector
for i = 2:n
    x(i) = a + (i-1)*h;
end

% Define the terms to be multiplied by 4
for i = 2:((n+1)/2)
    p = p + (f(x(2*i -2)));
end

% Define the terms to be multiplied by 2
for i = 2:((n-1)/2)
    q = q + (f(x(2*i -1)));
end

% Calculate final output
x = (h/3)*(f(a) + 2*q + 4*p + f(b));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interval `[a,b]` should be split into `n` intervals. This results in `n+1` values for `x` that form the boundary of each partition. Your vector `x` contains only `n` elements. It appears that your code is only dealing with `n` terms instead of `n+1` as required.

EDIT:: Now you have modified the question based on the above, try this

```
% The 2 factor terms
for i = 2:(((n+1)/2) - 1 )
    q = q + (f(x(2*i)));
end

% The 4 factor terms
for i = 2:((n+1)/2)
   p = p + (f(x(2*i -1)));
end
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will look into this.  The fact that MatLab does not begin indexing at x(0) will never, ever cease to annoy me!

Comment: @Kristian Yes it can make life confusing. It appears that at the very least you need to make `x` contain `n+1` elements, also `x(0) = a` not `f(a)` according to the formula. Similarly `x(n) = b` not `f(b)` (using the zero based indexing!!)

Comment: Thanks again.  I have tried fixing my code based on your input, but my answers are still way off, I'm afraid.  I'm pretty sure the indexing is throwing me off here, since I am basing my code on a pseudocode written for index-start at x(0).

Comment: @Kristian why not just partition the x into n intervals then use a loop over x to alternately add multiples of 2 and 4 of the function evaluated at the interior x points instead of calculating each sum separately. That might reduce some index confusion. Alternatively write out the simpsons formula using 1 based indices instead of zero based so that your code and formula indices match ??

Comment: @Kristian Does my updated answer help? I have tried recalculating the formula based on 1 based indexing according to the wiki formula

Comment: Thanks!  I actually tried your second tip (writing out the formula using 1 based indicies), and my updated code (which I have included in my original post), should take this into account.  Nevertheless, I still do not get my values to come out right.  I really, really appreciate your input though!  I think I just need to do some tweaking, but it's 11 pm here now, and I have to go to bed, so I will continue this tomorrow.  But thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The code you have created works just fine. The only problem I see is n. From my experience, try n>=10000 for any function.

Comment: The error committed by the composite Simpson's rule is bounded (in absolute value) by

\tfrac{h^4}{180}(b-a) \max_{\xi\in[a,b]} |f^{(4)}(\xi)|,
where h is the "step length", given by h=(b-a)/n.

Comment: You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29927648/edit) your answer instead of posting comments. Comments are more for clarifications/discussions with other SO members.

Answer (score 0):

```
function x = compsimp(a,b,n,f)
```

I don't know if this matters but shouldn't be `f` the first letter:

```
function x = compsimp(f,a,b,n)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correction should be in the parts `p1`, `p2` and `p3`. I tried it and got approximately exact results:

[image]

Comment: I love the term "approximately exact"... :P